# Issues with HP BL460c Gen8 - wrong processor(s) and memory showing?

Tags: hp, blade-server, xeon

I have searched all the posts possible (dip switch resets 1,5,6 etc) and reset via removal of Battery for days, still no good solution.

I bought a matched pair of Xeon E5-2650V2 2.60 GHz for each blade, They turn on with the red bar blinking along the front
I am trying the minimum configuration now with only processor 1 installed per HP documentation, and when I look in the bladecenter under information one says it has two 2570v2 processors and 64GB memory (it has one 2650 v2 and 16gb)
And the other says
The CPU information could not be retrieved. 
The memory information could not be retrieved.

Another one says it has two 2570v2 processors and 128gb memory.

How do I clear these blades back to factory default so they'll accept the new processors? The dip switches and removing the battery have not seemed to help.

The blades themselves are running the latest firmware from 01/22/2018.

Help!

Comment: You need a special firmware update; you can find it [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03911173&lang=en-us&cc=us). You will need to install an older Xeon in order to apply the update. Then you can install the V2 Xeons.

Comment: Hi there, I'm running the January 2018 firmware on these blades, would that not include this?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But I could be wrong; I don't have any G8 servers anymore.